# How to make a generic base controller with generic parameters in asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having problems with how to make a generic controller. I have Model that the id property can be type of string or int. When i want to Edit a model that id is int, i can't find the action resulting in an error, because i implemented 
a override method to public abstract ActionResult Edit(string id).

Exists a way to pass a generic parameter(string or int) that my route can be undertand?

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : Controller
{
    //protected UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new           UnitOfWork(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);        
    protected UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork("");
    public abstract ActionResult List();
    public abstract ActionResult Index();
    public abstract ActionResult Details(string id);, 
    public abstract ActionResult CreateByModal();
    public abstract ActionResult Create();
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public abstract ActionResult Create(T entity);
    public abstract ActionResult Edit(string id);
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public abstract ActionResult Edit(T entity);       
    public abstract ActionResult Delete(string id);

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        //db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}

 public class ModeloController : BaseController<Modelo>
{
    public override ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
       //Here i have a int Id im my Model  and the error in my route
        Modelo modelo = unitOfWork.ModeloRepository.Find(id);
        if (modelo == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView("_Edit", modelo);
    }
}


public class GeneroController : BaseController<Genero>
{
    //Here i have a string Id im my Model 
    public override ActionResult Edit(string id)
    {
        Genero genero = unitOfWork.GeneroRepository.Find(id);
        if (genero == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView("_Edit", genero);
    }
```

}

Comment: You can use `object id` as the parameter

Comment: You should refactor this so that you can use IRepository<int> or IRepository<string> - or you will need to create a custom controller factory that is able to resolve the controller type you require.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to overload each method that has `id` as a parameter:

```
public abstract ActionResult Details(string id);
public abstract ActionResult Details(int id);
```

Or to add a second generic parameter for the type of `id`:

```
public abstract class BaseController<T, U> : Controller
{
    public abstract ActionResult Details(U id);
    public abstract ActionResult Edit(U id);
```

Either way you're putting more responsibility of the *caller* to make sure the right types are used.

Comment: The first option would require implementing overrides that may not be relevant to the overridden class.  The second generic parameter doesn't require that. Unfortunately, as you say, without some additional plumbing there's no compiler help to ensure the parameters match.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an additional generic type parameter to indicate your key type for the given class.

```
public abstract class AbstractController<TEntity, TId> : Controller
{
    // irrelevant stuff omitted
    public ActionResult Edit(TEntity id);
}
```